# Force an Electron app to always use the light theme?

Tags: macos, webview, electron, themes, quasar-framework

I thought this would be easy but I haven't been able to find an answer yet. I'm building an app using [Quasar Framework](https://quasar.dev/), which uses Electron to build desktop apps. It seems that when my MacOS uses a dark theme, the Electron app will also automatically start up with the dark theme (e.g. black page background), which messes up the styling of the app. I want to ensure that the app always starts up with the light theme.

I thought that to enable support for system theming you'd need to change a setting in the config. But it turned out that this doesn't seem to be the case since I didn't change anything and I also couldn't find any related setting via a search.